# porque no me sale la imagen en la celda del datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

pasa que tengo una lista de empleados en las cuales pueden estar los que estan de alta y los que estan de baja entonces lo que eh intentado es cambiar la imagen de una celda dependiendo del estado en el que esten usando el resource intente con esto

```
    dg_Empleado.Rows[p].Cells["Eliminar"].Value = Properties.Resources.reload_webpage_icon_icons_com_53905;
```

y en la web encontre esto para añadir

```
 private void dg_Empleado_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(dg_Empleado.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
        {
            case "Eliminar":
                if(e.Value!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        e.Value = Image.FromFile(e.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException w)
                    {
                        e.Value = null;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

pero aun asi no sale la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `Properties.Resources.reload_webpage_icon_icons_com_53905`, ¿a qué hace referencia, a un `string`o a una imagen?

Comment: Ah una imagen guardada en esa carpeta de resource

Comment: El problema podría ser que en una parte es una imagen en un recurso de la aplicación y en el código lo tratas como un `string` que contiene un nombre de archivo. Prueba a cambiar `e.Value = Image.FromFile(e.Value.ToString());` por `e.Value = Properties.Resources.reload_webpage_icon_icons_com_53905` aunque no he entendido muy bien qué es lo que quieres conseguir.